# NSArray arrayWithObjects needs nil at the end, NSString stringWithFormat and NSLog() doesn't. Why?

Tags: objective-c

NSArray arrayWithObjects needs nil at the end, NSString stringWithFormat and NSLog() doesn't. Why?

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:<#(id), ...#>, nil] 

[NSString stringWithFormat:<#(NSString *), ...#>]

NSLog(<#NSString *format, ...#>)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do parameter lists in certain cocoa methods end with a nil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477985/why-do-parameter-lists-in-certain-cocoa-methods-end-with-a-nil)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309535/why-does-nsarray-arraywithobjects-require-a-terminating-nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `-stringWithFormat:` and `NSLog` can infer the number of arguments based on their format strings (the first argument). `-arrayWithObjects:` can't.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477985/why-do-parameter-lists-in-certain-cocoa-methods-end-with-a-nil